# IntelliJ IDEA overwriting printing in console

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have the following function:

```
def printProgressBar (iteration, total, prefix = '', suffix = '', decimals = 1, length = 100, fill = '█'):
    """
    Call in a loop to create terminal progress bar
    @params:
        iteration   - Required  : current iteration (Int)
        total       - Required  : total iterations (Int)
        prefix      - Optional  : prefix string (Str)
        suffix      - Optional  : suffix string (Str)
        decimals    - cOptional  : positive number of decimals in percent complete (Int)
        length      - Optional  : character length of bar (Int)
        fill        - Optional  : bar fill character (Str)
    """
    percent = ("{0:." + str(decimals) + "f}").format(100 * (iteration / float(total)))
    filledLength = int(length * iteration // total)
    bar = fill * filledLength + '-' * (length - filledLength)
    print('\r%s |%s| %s%% %s' % (prefix, bar, percent, suffix), end = '\r')
    # Print New Line on Complete
    if iteration == total:
        print()
```

When repeatedly called inside a loop, with every iteration it overwrites the prior bar in the console with a slightly more filled one. This works in Spyder, however when running the same function within a simple loop in IntelliJ, the console prints a new progress bar with every iteration? Why is this the case, and can it be resolved?

Comment: I seem to remember that IntelliJ does not support carriage returns in the output window.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can't seem to find anywhere stating this... guess there is no work around for some form of progress bar for large loops.